# Unable to use xssValidator on Burpsuite

Tags: xss, javascript, validation, burp-suite

I am trying to use the xssValidator extension on Burp using this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qS5PsxYY1uc .

I have installed xssValidator by going to the burp store under Extender tab-> BApp store and installed xssValidator. I have installed phantomjs and slimmerjs as shown in the video and have gone through each of the steps exactly as shown.

While the command 'slimerjs slimer.js &' works fine, the command 'phantomjs xss.js &' hangs and is stuck in a loop and won't exit unit I force it to exit.

Using the command 'phantomjs --debug=true xss.js &' I receive some debug messages(please see the screenshot).

I feel there is an error in the file 'xss.js' which is causing problems I might be wrong as this file was given to me as per the tutorial.[image]

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Why do you **feel** that there is an error?  I see none.

Comment: Please do not post text as images.